# MongoDB Scala - delete duplicate documents in a collection

Tags: mongodb, scala, collections, duplicates, document

If I want to delete duplicate documents in a MongoDB collection using Scala, how would one go about doing it?

Pretty sure it's simple but I always keep finding ways to do it in Mongo Shell.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [MongoDB Scala driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/scala/)

In this example, I'm use the version 2.1.0 for Scala 2.11.

I suppose that you want to delete all the documents with the same attributes repeated except the _id field.

I have four documents in a *users* collection.

```
{
  "_id": <ObjectId>,
  "name": "John",
  "surname": "Doe"
}
{
  "_id": <ObjectId>,
  "name": "John",
  "surname": "Doe"
}
{
  "_id": <ObjectId>,
  "name": "John",
  "surname": "Doe"
}
{
  "_id": <ObjectId>,
  "name": "Dione",
  "surname": "Elton"
}
```

In this example, we would delete two of the three documents with name=John and surname=Doe, keeping these documents:

```
{
  "_id": <ObjectId>,
  "name": "John",
  "surname": "Doe"
}
{
  "_id": <ObjectId>,
  "name": "Dione",
  "surname": "Elton"
}
```

I've used this code and it worked for this example:

```
val client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
val database = client.getDatabase("test")
val collection = database.getCollection("users")

val future = collection.find().toFuture()
val allDocs = Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)

allDocs
  .map { d => (d.filterKeys { x => !x.equals("_id")}, d.get("_id").get ) }
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .map(_._2.map(_._2))
  .filter(_.size > 1)
  .map({ids => ids.take(ids.size - 1)})
  .flatten
  .foreach{
    id => collection.deleteOne(equal("_id", id)).subscribe(
      (dr: DeleteResult) => println(dr.getDeletedCount),
      (e: Throwable) => println(s"Error when deleting the document $id: $e")
    )
  }
```

The three first lines are quite simple, we are connecting to our databse and getting the collection object. Then, we retrieve all documents from the collection. Note that the MongoDB Scala driver is asynchronous, so I've taken the future object in order to wait for the results, since I need them to continue.

Now comes the tricky part. I'm going to explain it line by line. First of all, we map each document to a tuple, where the first element is the document without the _id field, and the second one is the _id.

```
  .map { d => (d.filterKeys { x => !x.equals("_id")}, d.get("_id").get ) }
```

Once we have the tuples, we can group the sequence by the documents without the _id field. It will produce a map, where the key are the documents without the _id field, and the values are sequence of tuples, which represent each pair (document without _id, _id) with the same content as the key.

```
  .groupBy(_._1)
```

Since we're interested in the _ids, we need to get the value of each Map object, and for each element of the value sequence, the _id.

```
  .map(_._2.map(_._2))
```

Now we have a sequence of sequences. Each sequence contain the _ids of each unique document without _id. The next step is to filter the sequence, so that we only have those whose size is greater than 1. In other words, we are filtering the _ids that represent the duplicated documents.

```
  .filter(_.size > 1)
```

Le's take the n-1 first _ids of each sequence. They will be the duplicated documents to delete.

```
  .map({ids => ids.take(ids.size - 1)})
```

Let's flatten the sequence of sequence, so that we have a sequence of _ids.

```
  .flatten
```

Finally, we can delete each _id from our collection. I've done it by using the foreach method, and deleting the documents one by one. The documents will be deleted asynchronously since we are using the subscribe method.

```
  .foreach{
    id => collection.deleteOne(equal("_id", id)).subscribe(
      (dr: DeleteResult) => println(dr.getDeletedCount),
      (e: Throwable) => println(s"Error when deleting the document $id: $e")
    )
  }
```

Hope it helps!